# I can not see list items in ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, sqliteopenhelper

I am writing simple phone contact. I add people's names,phones,e-mails. Only names must be shown in `listView`. I can see list's row, but can not see names on rows. They are invisible.

**This method is showing infos of people:**

```
public List<Kontak> kisiOku(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    List<Kontak> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] kolon = {"id","isim","tel","mail"};
    Cursor c = db.query("kisi",kolon,null,null,null,null,null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()){
        String isim = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("isim"));
        Kontak knt = new Kontak();
        knt.setIsim(isim);
        list.add(knt);
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return list;
}
```

**This is my data class:**

```
public class Kontak {

int id;
String isim;
String tel;
String mail;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getIsim() {
    return isim;
}

public void setIsim(String isim) {
    this.isim = isim;
}

public String getTel() {
    return tel;
}

public void setTel(String tel) {
    this.tel = tel;
}

public String getMail() {
    return mail;
}

public void setMail(String mail) {
    this.mail = mail;
}

public String toString(){return isim;}}
```

**This is adapter part:**

```
    k = new Kontak();
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    list = dbHelper.kisiOku();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Does Isim translate into Name?

Comment: Pretty clear. There is no code that tries to put something in the items of a list view.

Comment: @MichaelDodd yes

Comment: And can you post the adapter for your ListView or RecyclerView? That code only pulls the contact data from the SQLite database.

Comment: Also post the xml code of the design of the list view item.

Comment: Show us more fragments of your code. How you bind data from activity, what Adapter do you use?

Comment: I solved this problem. Thank you everyone :)

Comment: @ŞafakSever: Don't put "[Solved]" in the question title. If you have solved the problem, you should post an answer (or accept a posted answer), describing the solution for future visitors.

Comment: @ŞafakSever Good to hear. Can you post your solution as a new answer and self-accept it? It might be helpful to others in the future.

Comment: I changed this block widely. It is not similar to this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your code snippet you are querying from the SQLite and updating `isim` (which I assume to be name field) in the `Kontak` object. The same object is being appended to the list. The other fields like `mail` and `phone` are not being updated in the `Kontak` object.

Also, the `toString` method of `Kontak` class returns only `isim`. Consider adding mail and phone number details to the output string.

Comment: No. OP is creating a new contact, setting the name, and adding that contact to the list. OP also states he only wants to use the name for the ListView. The function returns that list of contacts with only the name set, which is what OP wants. I suspect the problem is when they come to populate that data via the ListView or RecyclerView's adapter.

Comment: Yeah! My bad! I read the question as only names are shown, instead of only names must be shown! In that case, to debug the issue, check if cursor returns any data and also, check the contents of the list before return statement.  If the method returns data, as you said, the issue is with View / Adapter.

Comment: I solved this problem. Thank you everyone :)